# VS Code use different interpreter for Run vs Debug Run? Code runs fine in Debug, missing module error in Run

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

Background: My primary Python install (and Anaconda, VS Code) is located on a VM to which I don't have permission to write to many of the directories so I can't install modules in virtual environments. I have to write privileges to a network directory though. Using the --prefix argument, I created a Python virtual environment, via conda, in a directory on the network drive. I'm new to Python and VS Code.

I'm using VS Code to write a Python script and it uses several modules, one of which is h3-py. If I attempt to run the script via VS Code debug mode, it runs successfully. If I attempt to run it using the "normal" Run Code method, I get an error stating "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'h3'".

I can successfully activate the virtual environment in VS Code and if I run the conda list in the terminal, I see all the modules I need to be installed.

I've done some searching online to see if perhaps VS Code has a setting to use different interpreters for the "normal" run method vs the debug run but didn't find anything. I've uninstalled and reinstalled the module in question as well. The virtual environment path is hard coded in python.pythonPath in the VS Code settings.json.

Does anyone know why there would be a difference in run behaviour when using the two-run methods?

Comment: what is the `Run Code` method??? Just use menu **Run** > **Run without Debugging**, don't use Code Runner extension, create a launch config for your python files/project

Comment: Sorry, wasn't sure if the terms. for the "normal" Run Code method, I was talking about the play button in the upper right of the VSCode page (shortcut Ctrl-Alt-N).

Comment: don't use that button, use a launch config, nobody knows what that button does

Comment: Thanks for the quick and helpful responses. I've gone ahead and disabled that extension (it was recommended on some video I watched). I just run the Run without Debugging now and it works well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use shortcuts **"Ctrl+Shift+P"** and type **"Python: Select Interpreter"** to choose the python interpreter where you installed the package.

[image]